# Electric potential difference signs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, work, potential

> If the force exerted is in the same direction as the displacement, what can you say about the electric potential difference?
>
> a.) It cannot be determined.
>
> b.) It will be a positive value.
>
> c.) It cannot be measured in volts.
>
> d.) It will be a negative value.

I chose the letter (b) but my 12th grade physics professor said that it was a wrong answer and I'm not even close to figuring out why. It feels more intuitive that (b) would be the right answer. Does anyone know and can explain why?

The process of how I thought that the answer is (b) as per requested by the community guidelines:

I arrived to my conclusion through the theory and observation that: Because the force you exert is in the same direction as the displacement, the WORK you do on the test charge is positive, and the change in potential energy is positive. Therefore there SHOULD be a positive Electric Potential Difference from Point (A) to point (B), given that the force it experiences is in the same direction as the displacement. It turns out I was wrong?

Comment: This is a homework/exam type question. You should show some effort to solve it and explain your problem to do so.

Comment: Potential Difference is always positive as the word difference in mathematics (and physics) itself means the absolute value of the difference i.e. |V1−V2|.

However potential of a point may be positive negative or zero depending on the reference taken.

So (b) is indeed the correct option. I have no idea why your professor told you otherwise.

Comment: Also see the second question on this page http://glencoe.mheducation.com/sites/0078807220/student_view0/chapter21/section_21_2/self-check_quizzes.html#quest2

Comment: @CuriousHuman Would you mind adding the actual problem text? It will be easier to help you out, if the wording is clear.

Comment: @Doraemon Your interpretation of the phrase "potential difference" as always being positive is not exclusive. Different textbooks use the phrase differently and some mean $\Delta V=V_{\mathrm{final}}-V_{\mathrm{initial}}$ explicitly.  If you don't know the sign of the charged particle being influenced, you don't know $\Delta V$. OP's question is unclear because the context of the question is incomplete.

Comment: @BillN Yeah, actually the question makes no sense unless something more is mentioned. But again, making some assumptions we can say (b) to be the closest answer (given the current wording). Also I found the exact same question in several textbooks and even they used the same assumption. I added one link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

The work, $W$ done by the resultant force is equal, by the "work-energy theorem" to the change in kinetic energy, $K$ and to $\bf{minus}$ the change in potential energy, $U$. In other words: $W = -\Delta U = \Delta K$ (assuming the system is conservative, meaning energy is conserved).

The difference in potential energy is $\bf{not}$ the same as the difference in electric potential $V$ ("voltage"), instead one has the equality $\Delta U = q~\Delta V$, where $q$ is the charge of your object.

You know that your object is experiencing a decrease in potential energy, $U$ because a force is acting on it in the same direction as the displacement, but can you figure out the sign of the difference in electric potential, $\Delta V$ without any more information about $q$? Think about that.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the work done is positive, which by the work-energy theorem, implies that the kinetic energy of the particle increases.  But that is exactly why the potential energy must decrease, so have a negative change.  Remember, potential energy is essentially a bookkeeping tool that allows us to maintain a conserved quantity, the sum of kinetic and potential energy.  The work-energy theorem gives us the instructions for how to do that-- the work tells us the change in kinetic energy, so minus the work tells us the change in potential energy.